# Realm.io relationship query in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

So I have the following Realm models in my app:

```
class Person: Object {
// ... other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

class Dog: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    dynamic var owner: Person?
}
```

How can I query all the dogs a Person has? Let's say I have the following

```
let jim = Person()
let dog1 = Dog()
dog1.owner = jim
let dog2 = Dog()
dog2.owner = jim
```

How can I find dog1 and dog2 that jim has?

Comment: It feels like `jim.dogs` should return something useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog).filter("owner == %@", person)
```

Replace person with your object. See [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for more query examples.
But personally I think better approach would be:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var ownerID: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: That worked.. I tried something similar before but guess I was missing something. Thanks!